# What forms of prevention of STIs are there?

Tags: sti, contraception, sex

Other than the condom, are there any other methods of preventing contracting STIs?

If so, do any of these also provide an effective form of contraception?

Comment: This is an incredibly important question, and until recently, the two have not been studied *together*. +1!

Comment: The only (100%) form of contraception is surely abstinence, but I get laughed at for suggesting that to people my age :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CDC lists two:  [complete abstinence, and being in a long-term mutually monogamous relationship with an uninfected partner](http://www.cdc.gov/condomeffectiveness/brief.html).

Sexual intercourse naturally introduces microtears (small tears in the the epithelial layer) through which diseases can transfer between partners.  One might think that additional lubrication would help with this, but [the jury is most definitely out on that.](http://www.catie.ca/en/pif/spring-2011/research-update-are-lubes-safe-anal-sex)

I think it's pretty safe to say that if there was another clinically verified way of preventing STDs, the CDC would have put it on [this list](http://www.cdc.gov/std/prevention/default.htm).  (For example, they note that there are specific things you can be vaccinated against, namely hepatitis B and HPV.)  It strains credulity to think that there is a mechanism available that the CDC just forgot to mention there.

Having said all of that, I'll just mention the fact that there are a variety of types of condoms.  If you are in a situation where you need to use them (e.g. non abstinent and not in a long term monogamous relationship), you might be able to find a brand or type that works better for you.

EDIT:  A comment has pointed out that a cervical barrier method can reduce the risk of transmission of certain types of STIs.  Since that does not show up on the CDC list I mentioned, I feel that it's worth bringing up.  By no means is that a "safe substitute" for a condom (and I don't think anyone is implying that it is).  However, as a risk *reducer*, it should be added to the list.

Comment: I take it that a vasectomy doesn't act as STI prevention?

Comment: The answer depends on the degree of protection as well. Cervical barrier methods do decrease STD's, less so than condoms, but condoms aren't 100% either!

Comment: @Tim that depends on whether you consider a pregnancy an "infection" :)  (NOTE:  if you were being serious--the answer is no.  Vasectomy does not offer protection against STIs: http://www.webmd.com/sex/birth-control/vasectomy-14387).

Comment: @msouth well I wondered because I thought some may be passed from the testes. I guess residual bodily fuid pases it.

Comment: @Tim if you wondered it, it is good that you asked.  I hope my little bit of humor didn't make you feel bad for asking a question.  If you were wondering that, someone else probably was, too.  I don't actually know if there are specific things only transmitted by sperm or maybe extra-facilitated by the sperm's motion.  But I think it's basically like you said--the vasectomy takes the sperm out of the equation, but there is still fluid transfer, skin contact, friction, microtears, etc.